# How to convert Future[BSONDocument] to list?

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

The code sends a request to MongoDB using ReactiveMongo and returns `Future[BSONDocument]` but my code handles lists of data, so I need to get the value of `Future[BSONDocument]` and then turn it into a list.

How do I do that preferably without blocking?

**Upadte:**

I am using ReactiveMongo `RawCommand`

```
 def findLByDistance()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) =  db.command(RawCommand(
        BSONDocument(
            "aggregate" -> collName,
            "pipeline" -> BSONArray(BSONDocument(
                "$geoNear" -> BSONDocument(
                    "near" -> BSONArray(44.72,25.365),
                    "distanceField" -> "location.distance",
                    "maxDistance" -> 0.08,
                    "uniqueDocs" -> true)))
                )))
```

And the result comes out in `Future[BSONDocument]`. For some simple queries I used default query builder which allowed for simple conversion

```
def findLimitedEvents()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) =
  collection.find(BSONDocument.empty)
    .query(BSONDocument("tags" -> "lazy"))
    .options(QueryOpts().batchSize(10))
    .cursor.collect[List](10, true)
```

I basically I need the `RawCommand` output type to match previously used.

Comment: You need list of what?

Comment: Of BSONDocuments
The actual data structure returned should look like this Future[List[BSONDocument]]
In other cases I was able to access `cursor` so the transition would look like `db.collection.find(BSONDocument()).cursor.collect[List]()`

Comment: Unclear if you're asking about how to turn a BSONDocument into a list, or how to get a computed value from a future. Also, showing the code might help.

Comment: @vptheron Both but since I have turned BSONDocument to a list earlier I assumed it should be similar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot "get" a future without blocking.  if you want to wait for a `Future` to complete then you **must** block.

What you *can* do is `map` a `Future` into another `Future`:

```
val futureDoc: Future[BSONDocument] = ...
val futureList = futureDoc map { doc => docToList(doc) }
```

Eventually, you'll hit a point where you've combined, mapped, recovered, etc. all your futures and want something to happen with the result.  This is where you either block, or establish a handler to do something with the eventual result:

```
val futureThing: Future[Thing] = ...

//this next bit will be executed at some later time,
//probably on a different thread
futureThing onSuccess {
  case thing => doWhateverWith(thing)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact use-case (showing some more code would help), but it might be useful to convert from `List[Future[BSONDocument]]` to one `Future[List[BsonDocument]]`, which you can then more easily `onSuccess` or `map` on, you can do that via:

```
val futures: List[Future[A]] = List(f1, f2, f3)
val futureOfThose: Future[List[A]] = Future.sequence(futures)
```